# Making sense of a symbol manipulation in fuzzy logic

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I'm reading [Bede's Mathematics of Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic](http://www.springer.com/fr/book/9783642352201) and encountered the following proof for the absorption law:

[image]

where $\land$, $\lor$ and $\leq$ stand for "intersect", "union", and "include".

It is clear that $A(x) \lor ( A(x) \land B(x)) \leq A(x) \lor A(x)$ holds but I do not understand how it is transformed to $$ A(x) \leq A(x) \lor( A(x) \land B(x))$$

How to justify that replacing $A(x)$ with $(A(x) \land B(x))$ at the right hand side of $\leq$ cancels $\lor (A(x) \land B(x))$ at the left hand side? Or how should I interpret the transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Oh. It makes more sense if the expression is viewed in a single-line:

$$A\lor (A \land B)(x) = A(x) \lor ( A(x) \land B(x)) \leq A(x) \lor A(x)   = A(x) \leq A(x) \lor( A(x) \land B(x))$$

where the second equal sign denotes the equality between $A(x) \lor A(x)   = A(x)$ which in turns is included in $A(x) \lor( A(x) \land B(x))$, thus proving that

$$A\lor (A \land B)(x) \leq A(x) \leq A\lor (A \land B)(x)$$

i.e.

$$A\lor (A \land B)(x) = A(x)$$